# Getting 'password is required' error when trying to log in via github to VScode on macOS ventura 13.1

Tags: macos, github, visual-studio-code, keychain

When trying to log in to my github account after opening VScode I'm getting the next error:

`Writing login information to the keychain failed with error 'Password is required.'.`

[Before logging in](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KVOsz.png)

After this I approve everything on the github window that is opened, the window then redirects me to VScode and I get the next error:

[Error obtained after tying to log in](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zvdoi.png)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Btw I'm using MacOS ventura 13.1

Comment: From within VSCode have you signed in to your GitHub account? Were you prompted by VSCode to allow access to the keychain? Did you allow access?

Comment: @JonathanDodds thanks for your help here. I can see my github username when I click on the user icon down to the left of the editor, however, I am also presented with the option to "`Sign in with github to use github copilot (1)`". When I click that option the error is then repeated with the same `'Password is required.'` text  Also, I haven't been prompted by VScode to access the keychain.

Comment: VSCode stores credentials in the macOS keychain. The error seems to indicate that VSCode can't authenticate to the keychain to store and access the GitHub credentials. You might try closing all instances of VSCode, start a fresh new instance, sign out of GitHub, and then try to sign back in to GitHub. My recollection is that the Copilot extension has its own signin but uses the same GitHub account.

Comment: @JonathanDodds I did that but it didn't work. Now I'm trying to create my own "internet password" in the keychain to see if it works. I created a github token with full access to my account. Do you know what the name should be? I've tried `"github.com"` and `"https://github.com"`

Comment: I have a 'vscodevscode.github-authentication' item which seems to line up but I don't know for certain.

Comment: @JonathanDodds thanks for your help, it was a VScode bug and it was fixed last year: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/152964

Answer (score 1):

Alright, apparently this was a bug in VScode that was patched at the end of 2022. Here's the discussion:

https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/152964

So the solution is just updating VScode to the latest version.

Comment: Thank you! Trying to update manually uncovered I'd been unknowingly running VSCode from the `~/Downloads` directory, preventing updates from installing.